# Android : Geo Fencing Receiver not calling

Tags: android, android-geofence

I just made a demo for the Geo Fencing in android as per the documentation but here Geo Fencing Broadcast Receiver is not calling when I go out from the fence area or entered into it.

Guys look the code and try to catch the issue.

Thanks Kingo

SplashActivity.java

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        List<Geofence> mCurrentGeofences = new ArrayList<Geofence>();

        SimpleGeofence mUIGeofence1 = new SimpleGeofence("1",
        // Get latitude, longitude, and radius from the UI
                26.87473379143512, 75.78373555021025, 1,
                // Set the expiration time
                Geofence.NEVER_EXPIRE,
                // Only detect entry transitions
                Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER);

        /*
         * Add Geofence objects to a List. toGeofence() creates a Location
         * Services Geofence object from a flat object
         */
        mCurrentGeofences.add(mUIGeofence1.toGeofence());

        // Start the request. Fail if there's already a request in progress
        try {
            // Try to add geofences
            GeofenceRequester mGeofenceRequester = new GeofenceRequester(this);
            mGeofenceRequester.addGeofences(mCurrentGeofences);
        } catch (UnsupportedOperationException e) {
        }

    }
}
```

GeoFenceRequestor.java

```
private PendingIntent createRequestPendingIntent() {

    // If the PendingIntent already exists
    if (null != mGeofencePendingIntent) {

        // Return the existing intent
        return mGeofencePendingIntent;

        // If no PendingIntent exists
    } else {

        // Create an Intent pointing to the IntentService
        Intent intent = new Intent(
                "com.example.demo.ACTION_RECEIVE_GEOFENCE");

        // MAKE SURE YOU CHANGE THIS TO getBroadcast if you are coming from
        // the sample code.
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(mActivity, 0, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }
}


@Override
public void onAddGeofencesResult(int statusCode, String[] geofenceRequestIds) {

    // Create a broadcast Intent that notifies other components of success
    // or failure
    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();

    // Temp storage for messages
    String msg;

    // If adding the geocodes was successful
    if (LocationStatusCodes.SUCCESS == statusCode) {

        // Create a message containing all the geofence IDs added.
        msg = mActivity.getString(R.string.add_geofences_result_success,
                Arrays.toString(geofenceRequestIds));

        // In debug mode, log the result
        Log.d(GeofenceUtils.APPTAG, msg);

        // Create an Intent to broadcast to the app
        broadcastIntent.setAction(GeofenceUtils.ACTION_GEOFENCES_ADDED)
                .addCategory(GeofenceUtils.CATEGORY_LOCATION_SERVICES)
                .putExtra(GeofenceUtils.EXTRA_GEOFENCE_STATUS, msg);
        // If adding the geofences failed
    } else {

        /*
         * Create a message containing the error code and the list of
         * geofence IDs you tried to add
         */
        msg = mActivity.getString(R.string.add_geofences_result_failure,
                statusCode, Arrays.toString(geofenceRequestIds));

        // Log an error
        Log.e(GeofenceUtils.APPTAG, msg);

        // Create an Intent to broadcast to the app
        broadcastIntent.setAction(GeofenceUtils.ACTION_GEOFENCE_ERROR)
                .addCategory(GeofenceUtils.CATEGORY_LOCATION_SERVICES)
                .putExtra(GeofenceUtils.EXTRA_GEOFENCE_STATUS, msg);
    }

    // Broadcast whichever result occurred
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(mActivity).sendBroadcast(
            broadcastIntent);

    // Disconnect the location client
    requestDisconnection();
}
```

GeofenceReceiver.java

public class GeofenceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        Context context;

```
    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        this.context = context;

        broadcastIntent.addCategory(GeofenceUtils.CATEGORY_LOCATION_SERVICES);
        Toast.makeText(context, "Receiver", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        if (LocationClient.hasError(intent)) {
            handleError(intent);
        } else {
            handleEnterExit(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.demo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".GeofenceReceiver"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.demo.ACTION_RECEIVE_GEOFENCE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

It add the Geo Fence successfully but later it does not call the Broadcast receiver to get to know whether entered/exit

Comment: in your `SplashActivity` you are not handling the exception (bad idea, generally). Your variable `mGeofenceRequester` goes out of scope almost immediately...are you sure you want that to happen?

Comment: There is no exception occurring in my above code, simply receiver not calling but it should

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 3):

Android GeoFences never enable the GPS (because their API is awful and their device power consumption is already so out of hand). You have to set up your geofences and then constantly poll the GPS separately if you want geofencing over GPS.

Comment: Really? Poll the GPS? Do you have a link to that?

Comment: As of my comment in 2014, that was the reality on the version of Android I was on (KitKat iirc). I couldn't believe it either. The official documentation for the location API was nearly non-existent regarding how it decided to use GPS. You could simply include GPS among the inputs the location API used and little else. I found by experimentation that a "manual" activation of the GPS hardware forced new GPS coords into that API, making my geofences work with the accuracy I'd hoped for.

Maybe the location subsystem has been improved I haven't done Android dev for years.