# Xamarin Android Geofence doesn't trigger on GPS even if locationmanager polls regularly

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-geofence

Despite following the advice in the post below
[How to make Geo Fencing alert more accurate in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23708655/how-to-make-geo-fencing-alert-more-accurate-in-android/23741825#23741825)

and polling the LocationManager regularly I cannot get Android GeoFences to trigger with the device set to GPS only. They will only trigger if Location Mode is set to high accuracy (on Lollipop)

Has anyone succesfully tried this method in Xamarin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> They will only trigger if Location Mode is set to high accuracy

That always happens in the emulator. You should try in a real device